# Typescript library can only compile for react or for node, but not both at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, create-react-app

I have a yarn workspace with a typescript nodejs server and a typescript react client (using create react app). I also have a common typescript library, but no matter what I can't seem to get it to compile for both at the same time.

I'm not a javascript expert by any standard.

This is the index.ts for the common project:

```js
export * from "./interfaces/AuthModels"
```

This is part of the `package.json`:

```json
{
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
}
```

If I set the following for the common `tsconfig.json` it will compile for nodejs:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
    },
}
```

But then I get the following error when running the react app:

```
Uncaught TypeError: h.keyframes is not a function
    at ../../node_modules/react-hot-toast/dist/index.js (error.tsx:3:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ../common/dist/components/Notifications.js (Notifications.js:5:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ../common/dist/index.js (index.js:25:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

If I change the following to `tsconfig.json` it will compile for react, but not nodejs:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
    },
}
```

I get the following error running it on nodejs:

```
export * from "./interfaces/AuthModels";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Comment: You have 2 different problems. You apparently are including UI elements in your library. *That isn't going to work in node* (at least not without some effort): there's no DOM, no window, etc. In the ESM version you don't make it far enough to even hit that problem: node.js will only parse ESM files with export/import statements if they have a `.mjs` file extension. You will have to figure out what UI is getting included and from where. Are you using something like [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js)?

Comment: @JaredSmith "You apparently are including UI elements in your library. " - that's true, but I didn't think that impacted the following error as long as it wasn't accessed. I can separate it into a separate es6 library. How can you even tell from the provided code?

Comment: "node.js will only parse ESM files with export/import statements if they have a .mjs file extension." - it seems to work fine when I compile it for commonjs. Given that I'm compiling ts, how do I resolve this?

Comment: When I change the index to an index.mts file, I still get the following result:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/spierce7/workspace/project/@example/common/dist/index.mjs not supported.

Comment: "How can you even tell from the provided code?" keyframes aren't typically a server concern, that's an animation term. "It seems to work fine when I compile it for commonjs" yes, CJS is node's module system it will work in node but not the browser. "[ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module" yes, the two (CJS and ESM) are not compatible. You will have to use one or the other, not a combination of both. I could rant for a solid hour about what a cluster**** the introduction of ESM has been. "How do I resolve this?" factor out the UI bits like you suggested to its own thing and compile to CJS.

Comment: You could even compile to multiple targets: CJS for node.js usage and possibly UMD for browser consumption. Believe me, I wish I didn't know all of this stuff. I wish knowing all of this stuff was not a prerequisite for basic webdev in 2022. But I guess it's a (very aggravating) form of job security.

Comment: "keyframes aren't typically a server concern, that's an animation term" - that's the error on the react side.

Comment: "factor out the UI bits like you suggested to its own thing and compile to CJS" - so react will be able to use common js just fine once the react parts are out of it?

Comment: Yes. You would see it too on the ESM version except you don't make it that far. Code has to parse before it can run. Some react components can run server side (SSR is a thing) but all it takes is e.g. one unguarded reference to `window` to blow it up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250321/discussion-between-jared-smith-and-spierce7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to factor out any of the parts of the library that use browser APIs not present in node.js, or gate access behind appropriate conditional checks like so:

```js
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // do browser stuff
}
```

The "h.keyframes is not a function" error is telling you that something you are including isn't node.js compatible.

Once you've done that, you will want to compile the Typescript to the commonjs module format (CJS). Those can run directly in node.js, and since you're using create-react-app you'll have Webpack to bundle it for the browser side. That will fix your "unexpected token 'export'" error.